# Anchor Tag goes behind fixed navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This anchor works in Firefox but not in Chrome! I have a fixed navbar at the top of the page and hence the first 2 lines go behind it. Z-Index is not the solution.

The code below is the text paragraph:

```
    <a class="resume-anchor" name="experience">
            Text Here Text Here 
    </a>
```

The Clickable Link

```
    <a href="resume.html#experience">Experience</a>
```

The CSS

```
    .resume-anchor {
        padding-top: 40px;
    }
```

Could someone help me out with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<a href="resume.html#experience">Experience</a>` link is actually looking for the **id** `#experience`, not the *name*.

To fix this, your first `a link` must have the **id** `experience` as:

```
<a class="resume-anchor" id="experience">
    <!-- Text Here Text Here --> 
</a>
```

Also, in term of good syntax and as the `<a>` element refers to a clickable link, the *anchor* should directly aim the your text block, like:

```
<p id="experience">
    <!-- Text Here Text Here -->
</p>
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Thank You. That works!! How come every anchor tag document uses "name" instead of id then?!

Comment: "*The <a> name attribute is not supported in HTML5*" (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp). I guess Chrome just removed this functionality, or just more breakable if you don't have the good *DOCTYPE*.